# How to create a table from two tables or insert data from two tables in to one with any NULL's?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need help. I need to create a table from two other tables.
I am taking the long route with this, but if anyone has a better way, please let me know!

I created a table and inserted information from one table successfully, with the data populating correctly. Unfortunately, when I did it again to insert data from the other table it compiled successfully, but the data show `NULL`.

```
CREATE TABLE summary ();
INSERT INTO summary (inventory_id, film_id)
SELECT inventory_id, film_id
FROM inventory;
```

The code above worked perfectly.

But this code below even though it was successful shows data to be `NULL` in the column.

```
INSERT INTO summary (title, replacement_cost)
SELECT title, replacement_cost
FROM film;
```

I also made sure the data types matched.

Comment: removed confusing tags

Comment: I guess you want to `INSERT` a join of `inventory` and `film` or rather create a view that does that instead of materializing it (or at least a materialized view). But since you didn't post a [example] that's all one can guess, you'll need to figure out the details yourself. Or [edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: yes, I am trying to join two tables into one and have the data from both tables correctly populated. Is there a way to do this? I feel its hard to recreate from scratch to show you what is happening.

Comment: You feel it is *hard to recreate from scratch to show you what is happening*, well perhaps so but it is even harder to tell you where you are going wrong.  Also, what database are you actually using. It is not Postgres. Postgres would give an error on both the posted `insert` statements since the table `summery` does not contain the columns referenced.  There must be something missing. Voting to close.